# Comando destroy em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, knex.js

Estou iniciando meus estudos em JS e me deparei com um problema gerado pelo uso da função destroy.

Estou usando o knex e o Node.js para me conectar a um banco de dados MySql. Para tal, usei como exemplo o tutorial do seguinte link: https://zetcode.com/javascript/knex/

Pois bem, eis o meu código:

```
const options = {
    client: 'mysql2',
    connection: {
        host: 'localhost',
        database: 'teste',
        user: 'teste',
        password: 'teste@teste'
    }
}

const knex = require('knex')(options);

const getTasks = () => {
    knex.from('clientes').select("*")
        .then(rows => {
            const data = rows.map(row => {
                return {
                    id: row.id,
                    nome: row.nome,
                }
            })
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch((err) => { console.log(err) })
        .finally(() => {
            knex.destroy();
        })
}

getTasks()
```

A seleção da lista é feita, mas sempre retorna o seguinte erro:

```
node:events:355
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:211:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._notifyError (C:\Users\Bruno\Documents\js\curso-react-native\apagar\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:225:12)
    at Connection._handleFatalError (C:\Users\Bruno\Documents\js\curso-react-native\apagar\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:156:10)
    at Connection._handleNetworkError (C:\Users\Bruno\Documents\js\curso-react-native\apagar\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:169:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  fatal: true
}
```

Quando tiro a parte do finally que contém o destroy() o erro some.

Alguém pode me explicar o porque???

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o método 'destroy' é assincrono. Você tem que esquerar o metodo finalizar. Tenta mudar o código para:

```
//...
.finally(async () => await knex.destroy())
```

Comment: Oi amigo. Mudei, mas o erro persiste!